# How to configure VF page on the Button and how to roll back to the original?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am new to the `SalesForce` and had done some playground for the Account Tab with `VisualForce` (VF) pages. When I click on create New Account I see that its redirecting to the Custom VF pages, now I dont want that, I want original-standard create new Account page should be rendered. How to fixed this?

[image]

When Click on New Button its redirecting to the new VF page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Account and go to Buttons and Links, and check to see if it's being overwritten

Click on Set up, type in the Search "Account" and go to "Buttons, Links, and Actions"

Comment: Could you please provide exact steps ? I dont see Buttons and Links options

Comment: Thanx. Override Properties I used the Override With No Override (use default). Now its working